# tableofcontents* still numbers ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, memoir, page-numbering

I am using `\tableofcontents*` to remove the page numbering from the ToC but it still continues to number the ToC. What I would like to happen is that there is no page numbering for the ToC and then when the next chapter begins, I would like to start off at the number 1.

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapterstyle{bianchi}
\tableofcontents*

\chapter{Awesome}
\lipsum[1-5]

\chapter{awesome 2}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

If I add `\pagenumbering{roman}` before the chapter then the ToC numbering is gone but then the header is wrong (not in this MWE but in my actual file).

Comment: You need `\tableofcontents*\clearpage\pagenumering{arabic}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel That does renumber my chapter correctly but that does not unnumber the ToC

Comment: YOu can only suppress the page number by `thispagestyle{empty}`. Every page needs a logical page number.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel For some reason the chapter heading doesn't change from "contents" to the chapter name. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can't disable page numbering. You can only suppress the printing. This can be achieved by `\thispagestyle{empty}` or `\pagestyle{empty}`.

The numbering scheme can be changed by `\pagenumbering`. Here an example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\chapterstyle{bianchi}
\tableofcontents*
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: This won't work if the TOC has more than one page.

Comment: @egreg: I know. Should I add the information `\bgroup\pagestyle{empty}\tableofcontents\egroup`?

Comment: No; it's much easier with `memoir`.

Answer (score 1):

The `memoir` class has many more facilities than the standard classes. One is that chapter starting pages use the `chapter` pagestyle that one can redefine at will.

With `\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{empty}`, all chapter starting pages will use the empty page style

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\chapterstyle{bianchi}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

%%% in the front matter we want no number in the first page of the TOC
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{empty}

\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter

%revert to normal
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{plain}

\Blinddocument\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does it have the same drawback like `thispagestyle`?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel It shouldn't. The `\chapter` command issues `\thispagestyle{chapter}`.